# Scroll slides in RMarkdown presentation (revealjs)

Tags: javascript, css, r, r-markdown, reveal.js

I'm trying to activate the vertical scrolling option in my revealjs presentation for all the slides.

I've tried adding the overflow option in the css directly within my .Rmd which makes the scroll bars appear on the presentation but my slide still overflows and I can't scroll down.

What am I doing wrong here?
Thanks

````
---
title: "Untitled"
author: ""
date: "16 August 2018"
output: revealjs::revealjs_presentation
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)
```

```{css}
body {
    overflow: scroll;
}
```

# R Markdown

## Slide with Bullets

This is a very very very long slide.
Very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very long
````

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was able to do this using:

```
.slide {
    height: 750px;
    overflow-y: auto !important;
}
```

You can either add this to your presentation in the css styles,

```
<style>
.slide {
    height: 750px;
    overflow-y: auto !important;
}
</style>
```

... or in a code chunk as in the original question.

Note that this only worked for me when I also specified a height along with the overflow-y options.